# Two sections with one uiswitch? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, uiswitch

I have a working switch and a switch state that keeps track on which switch is flipped on using the Indexpath's row number and bool stored in a dictionary. While that works excellent for one section only. I am having a difficult time prevent it from spilling over to the next section as seen here:

[Section 0 Row 3 switch turned on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brTkq.png)

[Section 1 Row 3 switch turned on without me pressing it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1kiJ.png)

Is there a way to only keep switches on for that particular section? Right now I'm using two prototype cells one for the data I'm displaying which includes only one switch and the other cell for displaying the section header.

Here is some of the code I guess would be helpful in seeing what I put down:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("advCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! advDataCell

        cell.advDelegate = self

        switch(indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            cell.lblCategoryItem.text = foodCategories[indexPath.row]["name"]


        case 1:
            cell.lblCategoryItem.text = activitiesCategories[indexPath.row]["name"]

        default:
            return cell
        }


        if advSwitchStates[indexPath.row] != nil {

            cell.advOnOffSwitch.on = advSwitchStates[indexPath.row]!
        }
        else {
            cell.advOnOffSwitch.on = false
        }
        cell.advOnOffSwitch.on = advSwitchStates[indexPath.row] ?? false

        return cell
    }



func switchCell(advSwitchCell: advDataCell,didChangeValue value: Bool) {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(advSwitchCell)!

        print("This advanced filter controller has received the switch event.")
        advSwitchStates[indexPath.row] = value

    }
```

And what I am using to store the switch states:

```
var advSwitchStates = [Int: Bool]()
```

Comment: Store an array of NSMutableIndexSets. The index to the array is the section number.  When a switch is on, add the row to the relevant indexSet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different issues, first get rid of the early return when setting the name of the cell:

```
switch(indexPath.section) {
case 0:
    cell.lblCategoryItem.text = foodCategories[indexPath.row]["name"]


default:
    cell.lblCategoryItem.text = activitiesCategories[indexPath.row]["name"]
}
```

Secondly you need to track the toggle state with both the section and row as keys since you have multiple sections. The easiest way to do this is probably to make the key of advSwitchStates to be an NSIndexPath.

e.g. declare it as:

```
var advSwitchStates = [NSIndexPath: Bool]()
```

and then in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
cell.advOnOffSwitch.on = advSwitchStates[indexPath] ?? false
```

Comment: Is NSIndexPath the absolute index of the table? I am asking because once it goes to the next section it starts back at zero again. I have 169 rows in the first section. Section 2 goes back to 1.

Comment: NSIndexPath is a combination of the row and section so it will map directly unless you are adding or deleting rows in the UI

Answer (score 1):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you dequeue a recycled cell, like you are supposed to do. You need to fully configure every view in the cell, **IN ALL CASES**. That means that in ALL cases you need to set a value for your `advOnOffSwitch`.

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method you have a switch statement for section values of 0, 1, or any other value. If the section value is not 0 or 1, you return without setting the state of the `advOnOffSwitch`. If you recycle a cell that had `advOnOffSwitch` set on, it will stay on, which you don't want. Change your switch statement  like this:

```
    switch(indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        cell.lblCategoryItem.text = foodCategories[indexPath.row]["name"]


    case 1:
        cell.lblCategoryItem.text = activitiesCategories[indexPath.row]["name"]

    default:
        cell.advOnOffSwitch.on = false 
        return cell
    }
```

With that code, you force the switch to the off position to start for sections other than section 0 or 1.

Comment: I don't have any other sections other than 0 and 1. When I select On say the first row from section 0. it also shows On from section 1 of the first row.